# How can I write a loop to copy and paste multiple rows in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a very long table and I want to fit every 90 of cells on one page. I tried to write a loop to copy and paste every 45 rows a time but I don't really know how to. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Range("A47:C92").Select         (I selected 45 rows a time)
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E1").Select             
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 15.67
    Range("A47:C92").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Range("A93:C138").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E47").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A93:C138").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Range("A139:C184").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E93").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A139:C184").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern here so you can write a loop like this:  (I might have the incrementing a bit wrong but play around with it until its correct.  The important bit is the loop syntax).

```
dim i  as integer
for i  = 2 to 1000000
  i = i + 45
  dim z as integer
  z = i + 45
   Range("A" & i & ":C" & z).Select        ' (I selected 45 rows a time)
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E1").Select             
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 15.67
    Range("A" & i & ":C" & z).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u want to do. for example, If you have 1 to 300 data in column "A"  you want to split it into 2 columns where column "A" will contain 1 to 45 and column "E" will contain 46 to 90. so total there will be 165 rows to cover all 300 data. it will look like this ...

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

the code will make it look like below (i have shown 3 rows but you need 45 rows)...

```
1     4
2     5
3     6

7     10
8     11
9
```

```
Sub make_dual_column()
'speed up's the process
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim i As Integer, last_row As Integer
'last row of col A
last_row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'last row of col E
col_E_last_row = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'''every after 45 rows, copy the next 45 rows
'''and paste it in column E 
For i = 1 To last_row Step 45
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then            
        Range("A" & i & ":C" & i + 44).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("E" & col_E_last_row & ":G" & col_E_last_row + 44).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A" & i & ":C" & i + 44).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        'update the last empty row of column E
        col_E_last_row = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
Next
    ' delete all empty cells from column A
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

'back to normal default state
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```